# Web Scraping in a script tag in Python

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have managed to get the script tag using `BeautifulSoup`.Then I turned into a `json` object. The information that I want is within `data['x']` but it is stuck between b tags.
Example :

```
<b>infoiwant</b><br>NA<br>infoinwant</br>columniwant: 123','<b>infoiwant</b><br>NA<br>columniwant: 123'</br>columniwant: 123
```

How would I go about getting the info out of these b elements

Comment: .find_all('b') Should be enough to get the b tags. br for the others.

Answer (score 2):

Before converting to json, can you use the BeautifulSoup get_text() method? Maybe something like

```
soup.find('b').get_text()
```

Comment: The <b> and <\\br> are from a script tag in the html. So using the find b method doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

One method how to extract the data from `<script>` tag is using `re` module:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = """
<script>
var data['x'] = '<b>infoiwant</b><br>NA<br>infoinwant</br>columniwant: 123';
</script>
"""

html_data = re.search(r"data\['x'\] = '(.*?)';", html_text).group(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("b").get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
infoiwant
```